# How can I draw a Rectangle on a PictureBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to just draw a Rectangle on a PictureBox that is on a Form.

Writing text like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/849359/how-to-draw-text-on-picturebox) works fine.

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
using (Font myFont = new Font("Arial", 14))
{
    e.Graphics.DrawString("Hello .NET Guide!", myFont, Brushes.Green, new Point(2, 2));
}
}
```

but when I try to draw a rectangle like so nothing shows up.

```
    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        rect.Location = new Point(25, 25);
        rect.Width = 50;

        using (Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 2))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(pen, rect);
        }
    }
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you might have forgot to set `rect.Height` to something other than `0`.

Did you check if the rectangle you're drawing has the correct dimensions?

Comment: Wow! How did I not notice that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(new Point(25, 25), new Size(50, 50));
```

if you like it shorter.